# Splice arrays in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-splice

I'd like to perform a splice of sorts in [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy). Let's say I have two arrays, `a` and `b`:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 5, 30]])
>>> b
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 3, 31],
       [ 4, 41]])
```

which I want to splice together into the following array, `c`:

```
>>> c
array([[  1.,  10.],
       [  2.,  20.],
       [  3.,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan],
       [  5.,  30.]])
```

That is, I splice the values from the first column of `b` into `a` without bothering about the second column.

I could of course implement this myself pretty easily, but it would be nicer to have NumPy do it for me instead. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by mishaF is only missing the last step -- making the entries of the last column unique.  The full code to get your `c` (except for the dtype, which changes from `int` to `float` in your post) is

```
b[:,1]=numpy.nan
c = numpy.r_[a, b]
c.sort(0)
c = c[numpy.unique(c[:,0], True)[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything in [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) to do that. Do you need exactly that result (in order, second column with undefined value)? Maybe there is something close that would still be useful for the end goal.

Comment: Yea I have come to the same conclusion after checking the Numpy docs. No biggie, I will just iterate over the arrays instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could stack the two together and then sort.  However, this doesn't take care of the fact that you have two occurrences of the index 1.  Not sure this is a great improvement...

```
 b[:,1]=np.nan
 c = np.vstack((a,b))
 c.sort(0)
```